# Adobe Digital Editions - Transferring books to devices

Tags: adobe-digital-editions

Does ADE automatically transfer books to all devices attached to my account?

For example, if I download an eBook from the library on my desktop computer, will it automatically sync my eInk reader and my mobile phone?